# What analogy can a teacher use to teach a child about neuroplasticity?

Tags: plasticity, teaching-of-psychology

What analogy can a teacher use to teach a child between the ages of 8-11 years old about neuroplasticity? It'd be easier to explain this to an adult, but a child probably doesn't know enough to understand neuroplasticity. Do you know or have you heard of an analogy that explains neuroplasticity?

Comment: what's the age group?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that. Between 8-11.

Comment: Can you use some kind of metaphor to explain it to them, if you are not teaching them details of neuroplasticity? Since kids are very young."Brain plasticity (from the Greek word ‘plastos’ meaning molded)..."Maybe you can compare brain to a molding putty.I ,as adult, see plasticity of brain as a tree,having thicker branches where behavior is repeated,and thinner branches for things less repeated.Strong vs Weak connections.You could use any such metaphor to explain it to them. :) Neuroplasticity was never mentioned in my school,and I'm 25 now. :)

Comment: That's a good idea. Thank you. I also thought about building a new town, making it bigger and stronger little by little. The people of that town work hard and get the town to a city. And that's the same with brains. How is that?

Comment: That's actually better analogy. :) They'll understand it well,sounds like game Sim City.

Comment: Using that I came up with a story [like this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hUtQIUEsHvMf7KoUr2HwIyo3mkN8DxwqkhIEvu4tFEs/pub) I'm not big on writing but it tells the main idea.

Comment: You might try using a potato and a handful of play-doh. Which one is easy to reshape into a new object?